How can I get a "kilt" shaped cloth simulation to work with a fast-moving animated character?
I am modeling a Knight character, and his armor included a Tasset (or "kilt"). The rest of his clothing has been modeled to the character mesh and moves in an acceptable fashion, but I haven't been able to get a cloth simulation to work without it seriously deforming, clipping, and basically being unable to keep up with the animation. I have tried numerous variations (I currently have chosen the Leather preset on the cloth simulator, with increased stiffness). I have modeled the Tasset with fewer polygons for a "stiffer" result. the collision object (the legs) have a subdivision surface modifier for extra polys, and I have used several different collision settings. (As you can see, it clips badly). I currently have it 'pinned' in the usual way for attaching clothing, which seems to be the only part that does work. Maybe the cloth sim just can't keep up with the poses and speed of the movement. I have watched many cloth sim tutorials and have gained some insights, but the solution still eludes me. So I am seeking some possible solutions or alternatives here. I've even considered trying to make the heavy sections "plates" instead of cloth, but haven't worked that out yet either. I have considered that I might have to resort to adding a rig and manually animating it, but I'm trying to avoid that if possible.
The images illustrate the behaviors, (Frames 1, 5, and 15) and I have also included images of the cloth and collision settings.
Thanks!







if you really want a helping answer here, you should provide a blend with which we can play around and make it work. Just providing some settings isn't enough, because we have no idea how fast your animation is, how your rig works and how e.g. your scaling is.

i think the easiest solution is to slow the animation down, make the cloth simulation, and speed it up afterwards....

Cloth simulations are notorious for being highly fragile, and susceptible to glitching when used as clothing. Trying to make one work well on a fast moving character sounds comically difficult. I think your best option is to just use multiple bones and fake the movement physics with armature animation after the base still cloth shape is calculated.

Thanks, I kinda thought I might have to go that route . . .
